# Intellij IDEA working with Strings

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I use the latest version of Intellij IDEA (14.1.4) and I am finding something annoying.

Every time I try to type a quotation mark (`"`), it auto-completes a pair (`""`), and puts my cursor *behind* them: `|""`

I know this may seem normal, put I want it to place my cursor *between them* like so: `"|"`

Comment: Are you using a keyboard layout with dead keys?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page where you can disable that feature:  https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Coding_Assistance__Auto-Inserting_Parentheses_and_Quotes.html

Comment: If your link has the solution, please include that information in your answer.